# <a4j:commandbutton> doesn't show <h:message> created on its action method

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, message

I have an `inputtext` enabled with a `<a4j:commandbutton>` that has `id=subjectButton` next to it. When I fill that `inputtext` and click the button, a `disabled inputtext` is displayed above the first one, showing the added content. For each content on the `enabled inputtext`, a new disabled one appears above it.

When I click the `subjectButton`, if it's filled, the situation above happens, but if it's empty, I'd like a `<h:message>` to appear next to it, saying that's impossible to insert an empty subject. That message should appear only if I click the button. On the code below I'm trying to do that, Look:

```
 <a4j:outputPanel id="subjectPanel">
    <br />
    <h:outputText value="Subjects:"/>
    <br />
    <a4j:repeat value="#{insertDocController.moreSubjects}" var="bean">     
    <h:inputText id="inputSubject" value="#{bean.subject}" disabled="true"/>
      <a4j:commandButton type="submit" action="#{insertDocController.removeSubject(bean.subject)}" 
         value="Remove" render="subjectPanel" execute="@this" />

    </a4j:repeat>
    <br />
    <h:inputText id="inputSub" value="#{insertDocController.currentSubject}"/>


    <a4j:commandButton id="subjectButton" value="Insert"
                     action="#{insertDocController.addSubject}" 
                     render="subjectPanel inpuSubject subjectMessage"
                     execute="@this inputSub">
    </a4j:commandButton> 
      <h:message for="inputSub" id="subjectMessage" style="color:red"  />
    <br />
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

That's the method addSubject() called on the action property from the `subjectButton`. The message is set here:

```
public void addSubject() {    
        if( (this.currentSubject == null) || (this.currentSubject.equals("")) )  {

            FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Empty input!"); 
            ctx.addMessage("subjectMessage",msg);
            System.out.println("MSG  : " + msg.getSummary().toString());
        } else {
            SubjectBean subBean = new SubjectBean();
            subBean.setSubject(this.currentSubject);
            this.docController.getDocumentBean().getSubjectList().add(subBean); 
            this.currentSubject = "";
        }
    }
```

When I click the button and the inputtext is empty, `addSubject()` is called and the message is set, because I made that test inside `addSubject()` - (It's shown in the above code too) :

```
System.out.println("MSG  : " + msg.getSummary().toString());
```

And the message is printed on the console.

What's the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What's keeping you from using `required=true` on the `<h:inputText/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FacesContext.addMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) requires the component's clientId, not the message id.

Try This:

```
ctx.addMessage("inputSub",msg);//inputSub as clientId
//clientId depends on the final generated id of the inputField
//it might be subjectPanel:inputSub or formId:inputSub
```

Comment: It still doesn't appear.

Comment: You have to inspect the element using chrome or firefox, and see the final generated id of the inputfield. it might be `subjectPanel:inputSub` so `ctx.addMessage("subjectPanel:inputSub",msg);`

Comment: It worked! The id was form:inputSub. Thank you so much! I'm learning more and more here!

Comment: @Luciane you could have also used `ctx.addMessage(null, msg);` and have a global `<h:messages>` in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Could you make sure you are passing the correct client id to `ctx.addMessage()`? To verify, open the HTML panel of Firebug (or your browser's equivalent), find the `<h:inputText id="inputSub">` and note the *real* id set by JSF; try passing *that* id to `ctx.addMessage()`.

If this does not work, check the network panel of Firebug and the response sent by the server when you press the button. Is the `<h:message>` rendered correctly?

Unrelated to this, you are re-rendering the entire `<a4j:outputPanel>`, so in `<a4j:commandButton render="subjectPanel inpuSubject subjectMessage">` the other ids are probably redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! The id was form:inputSub. It's working now!